# How to separate navigation from header

Tags: html, css, list, navigation

Well ! I wrote a code for header with light blue background color width of 100% and height of 450px below the nav tag. I have also closed the nav tag.

Ideally the blue background header width of 100% and height of 450px should appear below the navigation and logo in result but the header still taking the navigation inside it? Why is that ?[See full code here](https://jsfiddle.net/mustaqimahmed/xwxyaphc/embedded/result/) I want to pull the light background down and separate the above nav elements.

```
<div id="brand">Mustaqim Ahmed </div>
<nav>
<ul>
  <li> <a href="#"> Portfolio </a></li>
  <li> <a href="#"> Resume </a></li>
  <li> <a href="#"> Behance </a></li>
  <li> <a href="#"> Contact </a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

<section id="header">

<div id="header">
</div>
#brand
{font-family: Roboto;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 50px;
 color: #999;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 10px;}




}
#header{

background: lightblue;
width: 100%;
height: 350px;



}

nav { text-align: center; line-height: 50px;  

}

nav ul { float: right;

}

nav li {display: inline; list-style: none;

}

nav a {text-decoration: none; font-family: Helvetica; padding: 10px

}

nav a:hover {

 }
```

Comment: Hi smoggers ! This helped ! But why do we use this css property? If the header is to be displayed under the nav and the code of the header is written under the nav after the nav's story (div) is closed !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `overflow: hidden;` for #header within the CSS:

```css
#brand {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #999;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
#header {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
nav {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}
nav ul {
  float: right;
}
nav li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<div id="brand">Mustaqim Ahmed</div>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="#"> Portfolio </a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> Resume </a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> Behance </a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> Contact </a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<section id="header"></section>
```